Lookup Customer Journey DE entry rowCount by using a field of a Data Extension
Hello everyone and thank in advance for helpfulness!
Let me preface this by saying that I am working on Marketing Cloud and, specifically, I am in the process of building a Data extension of reporting on my client's mailings.
The table I am building has the following structure:

Currently I have retrieved all the data, except DE Entry count , through Data View and SQL.
However, I would need a system that would allow me to automatically enter the DE row count of entries into the Output table. I would also add that many submissions are single sends, so retrieving the data with an Update contact on the CJ is an unnecessary effort, since:
A) Many sends are handled independently by my client without my knowledge;
B) Instead of entering an update contact as the first step each time, I might as well paste the values into the report table by hand;
Searching around, the most obvious solution remains that of using the API, however, I cannot find anything that shows me the process I had in mind, which I report below:

Get the column name value 'CJ Name' in the table i've attached above.
Do a lookup in the journeys between field 'CJ Name' and journey name.
Retrieve the entry source of the journey
Do a row count of the entry source
Update the row count value on the table in the DE Entry count.

In the meantime, I ask the community: do you see this as a possible solution, or do you know of workarounds to scrape this information in a less complicated way? How can I achieve via SSJS this result?
Thanks!

For clarification, of what value is the DE Entry Count for your client's reporting?
